# В NSMutableDictionary передать не строковое значение

Tags: objective-c, ios

в роли примера взял код [вот этого приложения](http://kurrytran.blogspot.ru/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-and.html) установил в свой проект и почти всё работает но у меня в проекте есть вот такой массив

```
    self.data = @[
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km",betweenDistance/1000],
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km",betweenDistance3/1000],
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", betweenDistance4/1000]
              ];
```

Если в крации то этот массив выводит расстояние от пользователя до маркера на карте. А в скаченном мной проекте в uitable данные выводятся с помощью словаря

```
    states = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[states setObject:@"Lansing" forKey:@"Michigan"];
[states setObject:@"Sacremento" forKey:@"California"];
[states setObject:@"Albany" forKey:@"New York"];
[states setObject:@"Phoenix" forKey:@"Arizona"];
[states setObject:@"Tulsa" forKey:@"Oklahoma"];
datasource = [states allKeys];
```

Как мне в setObject вписать значения массива? Т.е. массива не будет в принципе, останется только словарь, но в него не получается вставить значения массива, если сделать так

```
    [states setObject:NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km",betweenDistance/1000 forKey:@"Michigan"];
```

то конечно вылетает ошибка, а как иначе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать исправить форматирование, и тогда все заработает:

```
[states setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance / 1000)] forKey:@"Michigan"];
```

Но вообще хранить в "словаре" форматированные строки несколько неразумно, как по мне. Для этой задачи идеально подойдет `NSNumber`, а форматировать строку нужно именно там, где она используется.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало, так она в общем то в этом месте и используется (выводится в uitable) , а словарь нужен для того что бы второе значение передавалось в виде координат например     [states setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1234567]] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance / 1000)] ];
Вот только на координатах тоже запнулся, не подскажете как их лучше передать (там же получается 2 числа (напр 60.050043, 30.345783)) или такая строка используется для их вывода CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(60.050043, 30.345783), как их передать в словаре?

Answer (score 1):

Для хранение структуры координат CLLocationCoordinate2D в словаре можно использовать например такую конструкцию:
      **Пример 1:**

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordicate = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){.latitude=10, .longitude=10};        
    states[@"Michigan"] = @{ @"string": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance / 1000)],
                             @"coordinate": @{ @"lat": @(coordicate.latitude),
                                               @"lng": @(coordicate.longitude) }};

// Получение координат из словаря

NSDictonary *coordinateInfo = states[@"Michigan"][@"coordinate"];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordicateFromDictionry = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){.latitude=[coordinateInfo[@"lat"] doubleValue], .longitude=[coordinateInfo[@"lng"] doubleValue]};
```

**Пример 2:**

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordicate = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){.latitude=10, .longitude=10};        
        states[@"Michigan"] = @{ @"string": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance / 1000)],
                                 @"coordinate": [NSData dataWithBytes:&coordicate length:sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)] }};

// Получение координат из словаря

NSDictonary *coordinateInfo = states[@"Michigan"][@"coordinate"];
        CLLocationCoordinate2d *coordicateFromDictionry = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){}; 
[states[@"Michigan"][@"coordinate"] getBytes:&coordicateFromDictionry];
```

Comment: спасибо, отличная мысль,но  посмотрите пож-та на ссылку я там задал такой же вопрос но более развёрнутой форме т.к. компилятор ругается на оба ваших варианта.
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/415347/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F