# Вывести координаты словаря

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Собственно сам вопрос, как отправить координаты и название в словаре и после этого использовать их в CLLocationCoordinate2D?
Код который их отправляет

```
    -(void)setupArray{
    self.myLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.myLocationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation *startLocation = self.myLocationManager.location;
    CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:60.050043 longitude:30.345783];
    CLLocation *location3 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:60.040000 longitude:30.323994];
    CLLocation *location4 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:60.037389 longitude:30.322094];
    CLLocation *location5 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:60.037329 longitude:30.322014];
    float betweenDistance=[startLocation distanceFromLocation:location2];
    float betweenDistance3=[startLocation distanceFromLocation:location3];
    float betweenDistance4=[startLocation distanceFromLocation:location4];
     float betweenDistance5=[startLocation distanceFromLocation:location5];

    [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"###"];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:59.93 longitude:30.35 zoom:9];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
    mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    //mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    //mapView_.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    mapView_.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
    //mapView_.center = self.view.center;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:mapView_];
cellIdentifier = @"rowCell";
    states = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordicate = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){.latitude=60.050043, .longitude=60.050043};
    states[@"Michigan"] = @{ @"string": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance / 1000)],
                             @"coordinate": @{ @"lat": @(coordicate.latitude),
                                               @"lng": @(coordicate.longitude) }};
datasource = [states allKeys];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

И как я их пытаюсь получить

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    stateLabel.text = state;
    capitalLabel.text = capital;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(print_Message)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(print_Message)];
    [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"###"];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:59.93 longitude:30.35 zoom:12];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
    mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    //mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    //mapView_.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    mapView_.frame = CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 400);
    mapView_.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:mapView_];
    // Получение координат из словаря
    NSDictionary *coordinateInfo = state[@"Michigan"][@"coordinate"];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordicateFromDictionry = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){.latitude=[coordinateInfo[@"lat"] doubleValue], .longitude=[coordinateInfo[@"lng"] doubleValue]};
CLLocationCoordinate2D position4 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(59.934673, 30.330702);
    GMSMarker *london4 = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position4];
    london4.title = @"Заголовок";
    london4.snippet = @"описание";
    london4.map = mapView_;
}
```

Но компилятор ругается на строку

```
NSDictionary *coordinateInfo = state[@"Michigan"][@"coordinate"];
```

Пишет что expected method to read dictionary element not find on object of tipe NSString

И ещё такой вопрос: мне нужно будет передавать координаты не одного словаря а нескольких, как мне организовать это?
Т.е. изначально было такая попытка,(каждый словарь выводиться сначала в uitable и при нажатии на cell уже данные выбранного словаря отправляются на карту)

```
[states setObject:@"60.050043, 30.345783" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance3 / 1000)] ];
[states setObject:@"61.050043, 30.345783" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance4 / 1000)] ];
[states setObject:@"62.050043, 30.345783" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance5 / 1000)] ];
```

потом то что вывидите выше, но координаты так толком не передались.

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть опечатка в строке `state[@"Michigan"][@"coordinate"]`, где переменная `state`  у вас объявлена как `NSString`, а вам нужна переменная `states` типа `NSDictionary`.  Попробуйте написать вот так:

```
// Получение координат из словаря
NSDictionary *coordinateInfo = states[@"Michigan"][@"coordinate"];
```

Comment: Не, всё равно компилятор ругается, я пока над новым вариантом работаю http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/415540/nsarray-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5

Comment: Компилятор ругается, какую ошибку пишет ? и как у вас в ViewController классе объявлена переменная states ?

Comment: @synthesize states - правильно же объявил переменную? Ошибку такую пишет expected method to read dictionary element not find on object of tipe NSString

Comment: Напишите как у вас эта переменная states объявлена в заголовочном файле *.h ?

Comment: NSString *states;

Comment: У вас тип переменное строка `NSString`, а используете эту переменную как словарь `NSDictionary`. Попробуйте написать вот такую строку:  `NSDictionare *states;`