# NSarray конвертировать в две числовые переменные

Tags: objective-c, xcode

есть такой вот словарь

```
    [states setObject:@"60.050043,30.345783" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance3 / 1000)] ];
```

Значения словаря передаются в другую view, и из значения `setObject:@"60.050043,30.345783"` получается переменная capital (nsstring). Мне значения этой переменной нужно передать  в `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(60.050043,30.345783);` Туда можно передать только числовое значение двумя аргументами. Я беру переменную capital, и разделываю таким образом

```
    NSString* sourceString = capital;
NSArray* words = [ sourceString componentsSeparatedByString: @"," ];
```

Но вот как мне массив перевести в две переменные типа nsnumber -  как мне разобрать массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить `NSArray` из строки `NSString` можно путем, вызова метода `- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator;` у объекта строки, где параметр separator - это раздельная строка, по которому делиться исходная строка. Например:

```
NSString *sourceString = @"122,333"; // ex. 122 - latitude, 333 - longitude
NSArray *arrCoords = [sourceString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
CLLocationCoordinate2D clCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([arrCoords[0] doubleValue], [arrCoords[1] doubleValue]);
```